# Static casting to unique_ptr

Tags: c++11, c++14

I have a head file which needs to hide some internals for complexity and "secrecy" reasons. I've therefore a raw void pointer declared in the oublic header, inside the code there are static casts to convert the raw pointer to it's actual type.

Now due to general memory management changes I need to change the type internally to a unique_ptr (it's coming from an object factory now as a unique_ptr, previously it was a raw pointer).

So in my header I have this:

```
class SomeClass {
    private:
    void *_hiddenTypeInstance;
}
```

Is it possible to static-cast this _hiddenTypeInstance to an internally known unique_ptr type?

Comment: is it a `unique_ptr` itself? or does it point to a `unique_ptr`?

Comment: It is possible to cast `unique_ptr<Foo *>` to `void *` and back again, if that's what you are asking

Comment: maybe look into "pimpl idiom"

Comment: generally it is much better if you can to declare an empty base class and use pointers to that as your "secret" rather than void pointers. You can also declare the name of your type without defining its content. Both of these ensure that the content of the data remain reasonably secret, but allow the caller to write code that is less error prone than working with void*. If they have multiple void* objects how can you be sure they have given you yours back?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a direct answer of what you wanted, but a proposal how to do things nicer:) You can actually still use the memory semantics of `std::unique_ptr` with hiding the internals and without using the ugly `void*`. As others have mentioned, you should look into PIMPL, but to summarize:

1. Forward declare the internal type in the public header
2. Use `std::unique_ptr` with that type and provide a dtor for the class which holds that member (otherwise you will get compilation errors because a default dtor will be generated, that will try to delete the forward declared class and will fail to do so).

This would look something like this:

```
#include <memory>

class CPrivate; // Forward declare the internal class

class CPublic
{
public:
    // You need the dtor here, since when you implement it in the .cpp of your library,
    // where the definition of CPrivate is known, the dtor of std::unique_ptr will know how to delete it.
    // If you do not put the dtor here, a default one will be generated here which invokes the dtor of std::unique_ptr, and here
    // since CPrivate is forward declared the dtor of std::unique_ptr will not know how to delete it and you will get an error
    ~CPublic();


private:
    std::unique_ptr<CPrivate> m_pPrivate;
}
```

By using this, you can then escape the casts inside the implementation from the `void*` to the actual type.

As for the original question - you can always cast `void*` to a `std::unique_ptr<T>*` (a pointer to a `unique_ptr`). But I would advise to evaluate the solution above. Because the `void*` thing moves away all type strictness - e.g what happens if someone changes `T` ?

Comment: Thanks, I think I will have to live with the static cast, even though it has mentioned disadvantage. My problem is that I cannot expose the name of the class in the public header.

Comment: @benjist even if it is forward declared? What are the disadvantages of that in your case? E.g. Qt does that - they forward define QXXXPrivate in all the public headers.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand you problem in a correct way: here is what you can do. This example is just for understanding of a concept. You can use it in your own code. Since I dont have the entire code I cant write exact solution.

```
class SomeClass {
private:
    void *_hiddenTypeInstance;
public:
    std::unique_ptr<int> foo() {
        int a;
        a = 2;
        return std::unique_ptr<int>(&a);
    }
    void bar() {
        std::unique_ptr<int> temp_hidden_type_instance;
        temp_hidden_type_instance = std::unique_ptr<int>(static_cast<int*>(_hiddenTypeInstance));
        temp_hidden_type_instance = foo();
    }
};
```

Comment: I have no clue what you're trying to do, but it certainly won't work since it will try and delete a local variable that isn't even alive anymore.

Comment: what this does is that you get a unique_ptr from any method outside this class. You can cast your hiddenType to that unique_ptr and use and it will automatically get deleted. if you want to store it, you need to declare another member variable as unique_ptr<void>  m_hiddenTypeInstance as a private member variable. I thought you just want to convert it and consume it.